# I am trying to implement this using a circular queue. My program executes but says terminated succesfully when build&ran

Tags: loops, ada, io-redirection, circular-queue

LinkSort.adb file

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure LinkSort is

  type JobType is (Accountant, Analysist, Manager, Manufacturing, Programmer, Inventory, Sales, SoftwareEnginner);
  package JobTypeIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(JobType); use JobTypeIO;

  type EmpName is (Ben, Betty, Bob, Damon, Darlene, David, Desire, Donald, Dustin, Jerry, Kevin, Mary, Marty, Sable, Sam, Sara, Teddy, Tom);
  package EmpNameIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(EmpName); use EmpNameIO;

  type LegalResponce is (yup, y, yes, affirmative, nope, no, n, negative);
  subtype PositiveResponce is LegalResponce range yup..affirmative;
  package LegalIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(LegalResponce); use LegalIO;

  package IntIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer); use IntIO;

  type Emp is record
    Name: EmpName;
    Job: JobType;
    age: integer;
  end record;

  SortByJob: Array(JobType) of integer := (others =\> 0);

  SortSpace: Array(1..200) of Emp;
  Avail: integer := 1; -- Dynamic storage allocator.
  Pt: integer;

  Again: LegalResponce := affirmative;

begin

  while (Again in PositiveResponce) loop
    put("Enter name: "); get(SortSpace(Avail).Name); --Get emp info.
    put("Enter Job type: "); get(SortSpace(Avail).Job);
    
    -- Insert in appropriate list (by job).
    SortSpace(Avail).Next := SortByJob(SortSpace(Avail).Job);
    SortByJob(SortSpace(Avail).Job) := Avail;
    
    -- Prepare for next dynamically allocated node.
    Avail := Avail + 1; --Using static array allocation as opposed dynamic linked list.
    
    put("Enter another name (yup or nope): "); get(Again);
  end loop;

  -- Sort by job type.

  for I in JobType loop
    new_line; put("Job Type = "); put (I); new_line;
    
    Pt := SortByJob(I); -- Point to first node in job list.
    
    while Pt /= 0 loop
      put(SortSpace(Pt).Name); put(" "); put(SortSpace(Pt).Job);
      put(" link = "); put(SortSpace(Pt).Next,4); new_line;
    
      Pt := SortSpace(Pt).Next; -- Move down list.
    end loop;
  end loop;

end LinkSort;
```

main.adb file

```
procedure Main is
begin
  null;
end Main;
```

Stuck on what I should do next? I've tried to implement everything in the Ada.Text_IO in the main.adb file but errors occurred. I know i need to move something into the main file in order for the program to execute after it has been built. The output statement should be name, job type then sort space number.

Answer (score 4):

You’ve written `Linksort` as a library-level subroutine (that is, it will be separately compiled, on its own). That works fine for main programs, but if you want your `Main` program to call it you need to provide a "spec", in file `linksort.ads`:

```
procedure Linksort;
```

and then

```
with Linksort;   -- the same way as you 'with' Ada.Text_IO
procedure Main is
begin
   Linksort;
end Main;
```

However!
There’s no rule in Ada that your main program has to be called `main` or `Main`; the way you’ve written `Linksort` it will make a perfectly fine main program. Once you’ve got it built, on a Unix-type computer you’ll say `./linksort`, on a Windows computer `.\linksort`.

Comment: If this answer helps, mark it so (an upvote, or even a tick); don’t delete the question, like your colleague amb007 did after I’d spent time providing an answer, or the next time someone from your class asks a question so similar to theirs they won’t get one.

Comment: @juggernaut45: Although you cannot [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) yet, you can accept this answer by clicking on the [empty check mark](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/163188) at the left.